# Append matrices to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

```
testMat1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]])
testMat2 = np.array([[7,8,9,10],[10,11,12,13]])
testMat3 = np.array([[2,4,6,8],[3,5,7,9]])
```

Here are three matrices of shape `(2, 4)`

How do I combine them into a multidimensional array with shape `(3, 2, 4)`?

`np.array([testMat1, testMat2, testMat3])` works properly, however this is not
what I am looking for because I will be continuously adding more matrices to
the array. I need a way to append new matrices
to the array. I tried using `np.append` but it doesn't seem to be meant for this purpose.

Comment: Usually we recommend appending to a list.  Any sort of appending to an array requires making a new array with full copies. It can be done with suitable care about dimensions, but it is less efficient.

Comment: @hpaulj I see. But I need to work with the numpy ndarray, so I would be appending to the list and converting it to an ndarray repeatedly, which is horribly expensive in both time and memory. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know what's the trade off between between doing `np.array(alist)` repeated as the list grows, and doing the repeated concatenate.  Another way is to initial the array to full size, and "insert" the new arrays as they become available, doing your calcs on the appropriate slice.

Comment: The underlying issue is that a list contains references to arrays that can be scattered through out memory, while a multidimensional array has the data in one contiguous block.  If you want a larger block you have to make a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack()` to vertically stack the arrays.

In your case the command would look like this:
`combined = np.vstack(([testMat1], [testMat2], [testMat3]))`
which will give you the shape  `(3, 2, 4)`

You can continuously add more arrays and update it by using:
`combined = np.vstack((combined, [testMat4]))`
which will give you the shape  `(4, 2, 4)`