# lists are turning out to be faster than numpy in this case please explain how

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

Lists are turning out to be faster than numpy in this case. please explain where i am going wrong.
This is an implementation of data structure graph in python
I am creating an adjacency matrix  here
i had implemented using numpy thinking that it will be faster
but numpy version of code is taking time in millisec
and lists version of code is taking time in microsec to execute
Numpy version code

```
%%time
import numpy as np 
nodes=[]
graph=[]
nodes_count=0
def add_node(v):
    global nodes_count
    global graph
    #check whether node already exists
    if v in nodes:
        print(v,"node already present")
    else:
        nodes_count+=1
        nodes.append(v)
        

        #ALTERNATE FAST METHOD USING NUMPY
        if nodes_count==1:
            graph=np.hstack(np.zeros((1,1),dtype=int))
        elif nodes_count==2:
            graph=np.hstack((graph,np.zeros((1),int)))# adding 0 at the end of every row   
            graph=np.vstack((graph,np.zeros((1,nodes_count),int)))
            
        else:
            graph=np.hstack((graph,np.zeros((nodes_count-1,1),int)))# adding 0 at the end of every row   
            graph=np.vstack((graph,np.zeros((1,nodes_count),int)))#adding new row at the end of last row all zeros


            


print(graph)
print(nodes)

add_node("A")
add_node("B")
add_node("C")
add_node("D")
add_node("E")
add_node("F")
add_node("G")
add_node("H")

print("after adding")

print(nodes_count)
print(nodes)
print(graph)
```

CODE USING LISTS

```
%%time



nodes=[]
graph=[]
nodes_count=0
def add_node(v):
    global nodes_count
    global graph
    #check whether node already exists
    if v in nodes:
        print(v,"node already present")
    else:
        nodes_count+=1
        nodes.append(v)
        
        for n in graph:
            n.append(0)
        temp=[]
        for i in range(nodes_count):
            temp.append(0)
        graph.append(temp)
        



print(graph)
print(nodes)

add_node("A")
add_node("B")
add_node("C")
add_node("D")
add_node("E")
add_node("F")
add_node("G")
add_node("H")

print("after adding")

print(nodes_count)
print(nodes)
print(graph)
```

Comment: I did not try it on my machine, but from the looks of it, I'd say that most of the execution time comes from this line: `import numpy as np`. Try to benchmark a smaller part of your code, containing only the logic, on a bigger example (thousands of nodes). You'll have more consistent results.

Comment: Why did you expect numpy to be faster?  Read more about list append and the numpy functions you use instead - vstack, hstack, and their base, concatenate.

Comment: See my comments yesterday at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68915447/901925

Comment: As @hpaulj stated, joining array routines are kind of computationally expensive.

Comment: @m.raynal thank you ! it worked ,i tried bigger examples and numpy turned out to be faster